# Hey lads, kinda new to doing Python and was thinking for a bit about this

Tags: python

So, I tried to create a basic fundamental code for a "hit" option in Blackjack. There were like two other more complex versions and this is the most simple I've gotten. Does this suffice or am I missing some specific statistics jargon that makes this innacurate?

```
import random

valLi= ["two","three", "four", "five","six", "seven", "eight", "nine","ten", "king", "queen","ace", "jack", "two","three", "four", "five","six", "seven", "eight", "nine","ten", "king", "queen","ace", "jack", "two","three", "four", "five","six", "seven", "eight", "nine","ten", "king", "queen","ace", "jack", "two","three", "four", "five","six", "seven", "eight", "nine","ten", "king", "queen","ace", "jack" ]
random.shuffle(valLi)
random.sample(valLi, len(valLi))


while True:
    if input() == "h":
        print(valLi[0])
        print(valLi)
        del valLi[0]
```

Comment: If you want to grab the top item in a list and remove it, all you need to do is `x = valLi.pop(0)`.  Also, you don't need `random.sample` in there -- that returns a new list (which you throw away), and you've already done a `shuffle`.

Comment: Ahh, alright. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

valLi= ["two","three", "four", "five","six", "seven", "eight", "nine","ten", "king", "queen","ace"] * 4
random.shuffle(valLi)

def deal(deck):
    return deck.pop(0)

while True:
    if input() == "h":
        c1 = deal(valLi)
        c2 = deal(valLi)
        print( c1, c2 )
```

The problem with this structure, of course, is that it makes it hard for you to compute the value of the hand.  You will probably want to use a different data structure for the point values.